# What does the abbreviation CMT stand for?

Tags: word-usage, abbreviations

I'm watching a show about prisoners called *Jailbirds*. They're taking their commissaries and then the male guard said: "You wanna save your CMTs too." I'm not sure what *CMT* stands for here.

Comment: A CMT could be a crime of moral turpitude, or a person imprisoned for such a crime. Fraud, larceny, and having an intent to harm property or things, murder, rape, robbery, theft, arson, shoplifting, assault, kidnapping, fraud, embezzlement, burglary, transporting stolen property knowingly, extortion, blackmail, forgery, receiving stolen property knowingly, perjury, willful tax evasion, passing bad checks, bribery, counterfeiting, contributing to the delinquency of a minor, lewdness, or attempts to engage in any of this behavior.

Comment: Could you include the episode number and timestamp so we can watch the scene for more context?

Answer (score -1):

I found this link on google. It has all the definitions for the abbreviation CMT -
https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/CMT

Answer (score -1):

> I'm not sure what CMT stands for

In the [Bell (Texas) County Jail](https://www.bellcountytx.com/county_government/sheriff/bell_county_jail.php), a CMT is a Cell Management Team.

> The CMT is a team of qualified officers train[ed] to negotiate with inmates in order to get a problem resolved as quickly and with as little force as possible.
>
> —*Bell County Sheriff's Department General Orders* p.221 (01-January-2014)

I'd conjecture that CMT might have meant "CellMaTe" in the context of the *Jailbirds* program.